# Update or add new ingress http rules using kubernetes python sdk

Tags: python, kubernetes

I keep getting 409 while updating existing ingress of Kubernetes cluster using python sdk

I'm using patch method to update ingress

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.